# Is there an option for flowdocument that allow me to deny splitting blocks to 2 pages when printing?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, flowdocument

I'm trying to make a small label printer with c# 2010 using the flowdocument from wpf.

I generate the labels like this:

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
foreach (Labels label in labels)
        {

            p.Inlines.Add(label.name+"\n");
            p.Inlines.Add(label.age + "\n");
            p.Inlines.Add(label.price + "\n");
            p.Inlines.Add( "\n");
            doc.Blocks.Add(p);
        }
```

It´s working fine But when there are more labels generated then fit on one page, the labels get split. So for example that name is on Page1 and age, price are on Page2.

Now I asked you for a possibility to prevent the labels for being split.

Comment: If you are looking for a fixed page format then FlowDocument is not the right tool.  Look to FixedDocument if you want page level control.

Comment: @BalamBalam The FlowDocument would be appropriate if you want to print fixed size labels on any size paper.  The labels would fill up as much of the page as available before overflowing to the next page.  FixedDocument is better if you want the entire page layout to be explicitly set, which the OP does not.

Comment: @scott From what I read it sounded like he wanted to control the page formatting.  But I like you answer.

Comment: @BalamBalam  thank you for the hint about fixeddocuments. I heard of them before but everything except the page split worked well with my flowdocument solution. Therefore I didnt want to switch it and thought there might be a workaroung (as Scott posted)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  You can specify that a 'Paragraph' should not be split across pages or columns by setting its 'KeepTogether' property to True (default is False).  The only caveat is if there is not enough room for the 'Paragraph' to exist on one page then the 'KeepTogether' property will be ignored for the sake of displaying the content.  For this to work in your example, each label will need to be its own paragraph like this:

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
foreach (Labels label in labels)
{
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.KeepTogether = true;
    p.Inlines.Add(label.name + "\n");
    p.Inlines.Add(label.age + "\n");
    p.Inlines.Add(label.price + "\n");
    doc.Blocks.Add(p);
}
```

The last newline you were adding is no longer necessary as there is naturally a space between paragraphs.  You may even consider removing the last newline character on the 'price' line.